# What is the word for a rapt state induced by a yearning for the unattainable?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I cannot remember the English word for a known meaning. The meaning of the forgotten word from the dictionary is a "a rapt state induced by a yearning for the unattainable".

Comment: I put what you said into Google and got _[Sehnsucht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sehnsucht)_ and _[saudade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade)._ Is it either of those? Neither’s strictly English, but I don’t think there is a strictly English word that expresses all of that.

Comment: No I don't recall these two words. The sort-after word was not an obvious 'foreign' word from the long lost English dictionary - last viewed in 1973!

Comment: @GraemeCorlett: You can add additional details to your question and it would be perfect if you can include an example sentence with a blank that this word would fit.

Comment: Isn't it simply _longing_? [[MW definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longing): a strong desire especially for something unattainable]

Answer (score 3):

*Ecstasy*.  Medieval saints, including Teresa of Avila and Gregory Palamas, achieved this altered state of consciousness after intense fasting and praying.

From Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2014.:

> ecstasy (noun), plural ecstasies.
>
> 1. rapturous delight.
> 2. an overpowering emotion or exaltation; a state of sudden, intense feeling.
> 3. the frenzy of poetic inspiration.
> 4. mental transport or rapture from the contemplation of divine things.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like part of the English explanation of the German word [Sehnsucht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sehnsucht).

Answer (score 2):

The term [Saudade](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade) may fit your description:

> - (European Portuguese: [sɐwˈðaðɨ], Brazilian Portuguese:  is a Portuguese or Galician word that has no direct translation in English. **It describes a deep emotional state of nostalgic or profound melancholic longing for an absent something or someone that one loves.** Moreover, **it often carries a repressed knowledge that the object of longing may never return.**  A stronger form of saudade may be felt towards people and things whose whereabouts are unknown, such as a lost lover, or a family member who has gone missing, moved away, separated, or died.

Also :  [pining](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pining) may fit the description: ( from TFD)

> - a feeling of deep longing

To pine:

> - To feel a lingering, often nostalgic desire.

Comment: Pining - see also: fjords.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on.  My guess is **Nirvana**.

Comment: -1 You attain Nirvana to suffer a yearning?

Answer (score 0):

A close kin is awe, from dictionary.reference.com

an overwhelming feeling of reverence, admiration, fear, etc., produced by that which is grand, sublime, extremely powerful, or the like:
in awe of God; in awe of great political figures.

Answer (score 0):

Tantalizing Desire is the word used for yearning to possess something which is unobtainable. So you were totally tantalized by something.

Comment: To improve the answer, you should include a dictionary definition and link for tantalized.